# Increasing and decreasing value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I believe my problem might have a simple solution, but I can't figure it out how to fix it...

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MzZRjW)

```
let x;
let op;
let horamin = 10;
let horamax = 15;

function hora (x, op){
    if (x > horamin && x < horamax) {
        if (op == 'soma') {
            document.querySelector(".hora").innerText = x + 1
        } else {
            document.querySelector(".hora").innerText = x - 1
        } ;
    }
}


document.querySelector(".horaU").addEventListener('click', (event) = > {
        x = parseInt(document.querySelector(".hora").innerText);
        op = "soma";
        hora(x, op);
        //document.querySelector(".hora").innerText = x+1;
});

document.querySelector(".horaD").addEventListener('click', (event) = > {
        x = parseInt(document.querySelector(".hora").innerText);
        op = "diminui";
        hora(x, op)
});
```

Everything works as intendend, ***until*** I reach `horamin` or `horamax` value. Then it just stops working, no matter how much I click. How can I fix it?

Comment: What errors are in the console?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `x` exceeds the bounds of `horamin` and `horamax`?  Your `hora()` function is designed to do nothing when it exceeds those bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number gets out of range you just block increasing & decreasing, I guess you want to always allow one of the actions:

```
  if (op == 'soma') {
    if(x >= horamax) return;
    document.querySelector(".hora").innerText = x +1
  } else {
    if(x <= horamin) return;
    document.querySelector(".hora").innerText = x -1
  }
```